# How can I get a conditional checboxInput to make a ggplot graph?

Tags: r, shiny

So I have been having a hard time trying to get a conditional checkboxInput to make a ggplot graph. I am just wondering what I am doing wrong on the `server.R` file?

I can't seem to produce this ggplot graph using the msleep dataset: `ggplot(newData, aes(x = bodywt, y = sleep_total, color= conservation, alpha=sleep_rem))+geom_point()`.

**ui.R**:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel(uiOutput("title_panel")),

  # Sidebar with options for the data set
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("vore", "Vore", selected = "omni", choices = levels(as.factor(msleep$vore))),
      br(),
      sliderInput("size", "Size of Points",
              min = 1, max = 10, value = 5, step = 1),
      checkboxInput("conservation", h4("Color Code Conservation Status", style = "color:green;")),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.conservation==true",
        checkboxInput("symbol", p("Also change symbol based off of REM sleep?", style = "color:black;"))
      )
  ),

  # Show outputs
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("sPlot"),
  )
 )
))
```

**server.R**:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  get.data <- reactive({
    new.data <- msleep %>% filter(vore == input$vore)
  })
  output$sPlot <- renderPlot({
    new.data <- get.data()

    g <- ggplot(new.data, aes(x = bodywt, y = sleep_total))

    if(input$conservation){
      g + geom_point(size = input$size, aes(col = conservation))
    } else if(input$symbol){#Currently I can't seem to produce this ggplot below
      ggplot(newData, aes(x = bodywt, y = sleep_total, color= conservation, alpha=sleep_rem))+geom_point()
    } else {
      g + geom_point(size = input$size)
    }
  })
})
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `ggplot(newData, aes(x = bodywt, y = sleep_total, color= conservation, alpha=sleep_rem))` doesn't include any geoms. How exactly do you want to plot that data? Do you want to use points? If so, add `+ geom_poin()` to the end.

Comment: Hi @MrFlick. Yes, I wanted to use points. However, even though I add in `geom_point`, I still can't see the data that I want to plot.

Comment: This example seems to be incomplete. There is code looking at `input$vore` and `input$size` which do not exist in the UI

Comment: Hi @MrFlick, just added the `input$vore` and `input$size` in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic was incorrect.  You only display the second checkbox, if the first checkbox is checked (TRUE).  In that case, the logic should follow the same.  Try this...

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  get.data <- reactive({
    new.data <- msleep %>% filter(vore == input$vore)
  })
  output$sPlot <- renderPlot({
    new.data <- get.data()
    
    g <- ggplot(new.data, aes(x = bodywt, y = sleep_total))
    
    if(input$conservation){
      if(input$symbol){
        g <- g + geom_point(aes(color= conservation, alpha=sleep_rem, size = input$size))
      }else g <- g + geom_point(size = input$size, aes(col = conservation))
    } else {
      g <- g + geom_point(size = input$size)
    }
    g
  })
})
```